# Spyder 3.1.2 hangs at Python Console

Tags: spyder

When ask Spyder to run my program from the Python Console it gives me different responses.  Sometimes, it doesn't run the program, other times it hangs.  When it hangs I have to manual break the program with Ctrl+enter.
Have I loaded Spyder incorrectly?  Do I need to configure my interface differently?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) Because of this and several other bugs, the Python console is going to be removed in Spyder **3.2**.

Please use the IPython console instead.